# Javascript ECMA6 basic , variable is not defined in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-6

Trying to write a simple class to update a javascript List .

```
  class ep_List {

     constructor()
     {
        this.urlForAjax ='';
        this.dataList=[];
        this.dataJson='';
        this.dataParams={};
     }

     getData(method,params,url)
     {
       this.urlForAjax = url;
       this.dataParams=params;

       if(method=='get')
        this.callGetAjax();
      else
        this.callPostAjax();
     }

     callPostAjax()
     { 
        $.post(this.urlForAjax,this.dataParams,this.setList(res));
     }

     callGetAjax()
     {
        $.get(this.urlForAjax,this.setList(res));
     }

     setList(res)
     {
        console.log(res);
        this.dataList =res;
     }

  }

  class gasFilter extends ep_List {


    displayList()
    {
        //console.log(this.dataList);
      $.each(this.dataList,function(val){
         console.log('sss');
      });
    }
  }

var gasObj = new gasFilter();

gasObj.getData('get','','mapper/?mtc=101');
```

I am getting error as

> Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined
>       at gasFilter.callGetAjax (app.js [sm]:140)
>       at gasFilter.getData (app.js [sm]:140)
>       at HTMLDocument. (app.js [sm]:140)
>       at j (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at k (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)

Suggestions are welcome

Thanks

Comment: What do you not understand about this error? In `callPostAjax` and `callGetAjax` you're using `res` variable, which is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone else coming here this is the working code.

```
  class ep_List {

     constructor()
     {
        this.urlForAjax ='';
        this.dataList=[];
        this.dataJson='';
        this.dataParams={};
     }

     getData(method,params,url)
     {
       this.urlForAjax = url;
       this.dataParams=params;

       if(method=='get')
        this.callGetAjax();
       else
        this.callPostAjax();
     }

     callPostAjax()
     { 
        $.post(this.urlForAjax,this.dataParams,this.setList.bind(this));
     }

     callGetAjax()
     {
        $.get(this.urlForAjax,this.setList.bind(this));
     }

     setList(res)
     {

        this.dataList =res;
        console.log({dataList:this.dataList});
     }



  }

  class gasFilter extends ep_List {


    displayList()
    {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Gotta make sure you call this.dataList
            that.dataList.forEach(function(val){
                console.log(val);
            });
        }, 3000);

    }
  }

var gasObj = new gasFilter();

gasObj.getData('get','','mapper/?mtc=101');
gasObj.displayList();
```

Answer (score 7):

You need the success paramter of $.post and $.get to be a callback function so try changing it to something like this:

```
 callPostAjax()
 { 
    $.post(this.urlForAjax,this.dataParams, res => this.setList(res));
 }

 callGetAjax()
 {
    $.get(this.urlForAjax, res => this.setList(res));
 }
```

You can skip the arrow function and if you use `this.setList.bind(this)` in it's place. The trick is you need `this` to be set correctly in `.setList()`. You may want to read more about how [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) affect scope.

Also, you need to use this.dataList, not just dataList, in the second class.

Here's a working, modified version of your code.

```js
class ep_List {

     constructor()
     {
        this.urlForAjax ='';
        this.dataList=[];
        this.dataJson='';
        this.dataParams={};
     }

     getData(method,params,url)
     {
       this.urlForAjax = url;
       this.dataParams=params;

       if(method=='get')
        this.callGetAjax();
      else
        this.callPostAjax();
        
      // Added to I could chain a call to .displayList()
      return this;

     }
     
     getFakeData(cb)
     {
       let data = [1,2,3]
       cb(data)
     }

     callPostAjax()
     { 
        this.getFakeData(this.setList.bind(this));
     }

     callGetAjax()
     {
        this.getFakeData(this.setList.bind(this));
     }

     setList(res)
     {
        console.log(res);
        this.dataList = res;
        console.log({dataList: this.dataList})
     }

  }

  class gasFilter extends ep_List {


    displayList()
    {
      // Gotta make sure you call this.dataList
      this.dataList.forEach(function(val){
         console.log('sss');
      });
    }
  }

var gasObj = new gasFilter();

gasObj.getData('get','','mapper/?mtc=101').displayList();
```

Comment: @jamesKraus thanks , it worked , But I am trying to update the dataList, inside my setList() function but when i try to access that in the child class , it still shows empty list

Comment: Yeah, you needed to reference this.dataList. I modified your code and added it above.

Comment: I tried your Idea but still in the Child class it is an empty list , I think its the problem of Ajax, So when I did console log inside DisplayList() function it return first and then the console log of callGetAjax() .

Comment: I fixed it by adding a setTimeout of 3 seconds in the DisplayList() function

Comment: @Vikram the reason you are having trouble is because the $.get() operation is asynchronous but the displayList() is being called synchronously. You can fix this by either calling displayList() from inside the callback (eg at the end of setList()) or through restructuring with a promise operation. 

But basically you are trying to use the datalist before the response comes back from the server. A timeout isn't a great solution in case the server ever takes more than 3 seconds to respond.

Comment: @dgeare yes , Maybe I should google about how to write a promise in js

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setList(res)
```

is invoking a function with, an undefined, variable res. You need to pass jquery's get with a callback either as james suggested or simply removing the invoking parenthesis

```
$.get(this.urlForAjax,this.setList.bind(this));
```

the .bind maintaining the *this* scope in the same way the double arrow function does.

Comment: just another question , so when I am trying to set the `dataList` variable in the callback setList method and then I tried to access that in the child class but still the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are executing `this.setList(res)` right away. What you want to do is *send* the function as a parameter.

```
callPostAjax()
{ 
    $.post(this.urlForAjax,this.dataParams,this.setList);
}

callGetAjax()
{
   $.get(this.urlForAjax,this.setList);
}
```